# Converting a list of datetime objects using drange to plot in matplotlib gives an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a list of datetime objects which I want to eventually plot within a set range. However when I define this range using drange, I get an error **"ValueError: Number of samples, -23, must be non-negative."**

Any suggestions where I am going wrong here? Pretty sure my data has no negative values in it.

I'm using Python 3.6.

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

date = [datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 23, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 17, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 11, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 9, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 2, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 1, 0, 0)]

start = date[0] #is a datetime.datetime object according to type
end = date[-1]  #is a datetime.datetime object according to type   
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=5)
dates = mdates.drange(start, end, delta)
print(dates)
plt.plot(dates, y_data)


#    raise ValueError("Number of samples, %s, must be non-negative." % num)

# ValueError: Number of samples, -23, must be non-negative.
```

Comment: I see that `end` is less than `start` but `delta` is positive. `drange` works like `range`. It expects to begin with `start` and change it by amount `delta` until it reaches `end`. I suspect that you should be using `-delta` in this statement. However, `y_delta` hasn't been defined.

Comment: @BillBell Maybe you want to turn your comment into an answer, which can be accepted, such that the question won't stay unsolved forever. Since you found the cause of the error and the possible solution, you have all that's needed for an answer. If in addition you want to provide a runnable example, simply use `y_data = range(len(dates))`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: OK, thank you, I've done that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that `end` is less than `start` but `delta` is positive. `drange` works like `range`. It expects to begin with `start` and change it by amount `delta` until it reaches `end`. I suspect that you should be using `-delta` in this statement.

As suggested by ImportanceOfBeingErnest in a comment, you could define `y_data` using:

`y_data = range(len(dates))`